# Upload Parquet file to S3 Subfolders

Tags: if-statement, amazon-s3, file-upload, boto3, with-statement

[I have attached the code as picture, please find the attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc0ZS.png)I have shared the code as picture, please find the attachment

I have 2 folders, each folder will have 1 parquet zip file.

Example:

- Folder-A `xxx_timestamp.Parquet.zip` file
- Folder-B `xxx_abc_timestamp.Parquet.zip` file

Need to upload to subfolders in S3 bucket and screen shot of the code is attached.

1. Folder-A `xxx_timestamp.Parquet.zip` file should upload to s4/dev/A Folder
2. Folder-B `xxx_abc_timestamp.Parquet.zip` file should upload to s4/dev/x/b Folder

I am using Variables for the files.

Issue:- Both files are loading into the same folder s4/dev/A Folder.

Please let me know the suggestion or changes to be done.

I tried Boto3 and the code is attached but not able to achieve, need your suggestion.

Comment: You mention a screenshot and "code is attached", but I can't see them in your question?

Comment: How are the files being uploaded? Are you saying that they should be uploaded _directly_ to those folders, or they should be _moved_ to those folders are uploading? Please Edit your question and show us the code for how they are being uploaded.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Give the value of key as below when you are calling `upload_fileobj`

```
keyA=f's4/dev/A/{filename}.parquet.gzip'
keyB=f's4/dev/x/b/{filename}.parquet.gzip'
import boto3
s3=boto3.client('s3')
with open(LOCAL_FILENAME1,'rb') as f:

     s3.upload_fileobj(f, Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,Key=keyA)
with open(LOCAL_FILENAME2,'rb') as f:

     s3.upload_fileobj(f, Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,Key=keyB)
```

:)